# What does "etwas ordnen aus" mean?

Tags: meaning, translation, word-usage, difference

The verb "ordnen" means to organize or to arrange but how does the addition of the preposition "aus" change the meaning? z.B. *Er **ordnet** Wörtern **aus** Symbolen des Alphabets A Wörter über dem Alphabet B zu*.

Comment: "Zuordnen" and "ordnen" are different verbs! And franlky speaking it's not quite clear what you're asking about.

Comment: "Aus" does not change the meaning of the verb here. It adds information: where does the protagonist take the things from that he is going to (re-)arrange. - *Er ordnet Schrauben Muttern zu*. --> *Er ordnet Schrauben aus dem grünen Kasten Muttern aus dem roten Kasten zu.* The *aus dem x* parts tell us where the person takes the hardware from.

Answer (score 3):

The verb is *"zuordnen"*: *"Er ordnet X (dat.) Y (acc.) zu"* means *"He assigns Y to X"*. Here *X* is *"Wörter aus Symbolen des Alphabets A"*, i.e., *"words constructed from symbols of the alphabet A"*, and similarly *Y* is *"Wörter über dem Alphabet B"*, i.e., *"words over the alphabet B"*. Putting everything together, you get *"he assigns words over the alphabet B to words constructed from symbols of the alphabet A"*, or equivalently *"he assigns to each word over the alphabet A a word over the alphabet B"*.

Answer (score 1):

Your verb is not ordnen but zuordnen (to assign).
Er ordnet ... zu.

"aus" is related to the alphabet symbols. He assigns words **from** (this is "aus") symbols... by the way this phrase sounds strange so I can't get what the part with symbols is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting where the *aus* belongs!

The general sentence is:

> Er ordnet Wörtern Wörter zu

The verb here is *zuordnen* - a separable verb, which is why it says *Er ordnet ... zu*

All the other stuff is just there to closer define the kind of words that are being assigned. There are two kinds of words here

> Wörter aus Symbolen des Alphabets A
>   Wörter über dem Alphabet B

So together it says

> Er ordnet *[Wörtern aus Symbolen des Alphabets A]* *[Wörter über dem Alphabet B]* zu.

I'm using the square brackets here to make clearer what belongs together.
There is no *ordnen aus* here.